# Update a page when event receives

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, auto-update

I'm using the facebook messanger API to write a facebook chat. When I receive an update event from facebook ( Knowing that a new message has been received by the page ) I need to update, just that part of the page where shows the earlier msges.

Webhook that receives these updates is location in index.js, while the msg functions are located in facebook.js .

Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you want to update the fb page itself? ... or...  reply to the user's message which the page received?

Comment: No, I have developed a chat platform of my own using the facebook API. So  I will be notified when my page  receives a msg, in form of an event(in server-side ) ! now I need to just bring that msg at where it belongs in the messenger page ( that I have developed in my application ) ( The application already can bring up all the older msges but the new one won't come before a refresh )

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused by exactly what you are working on, but I am assuming a web app of some kind.  With that said, if you require both JavaScript files in the index.html, then you can call functions from each file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="facebook.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = someFunction() from index.js;
    var y = differentFunction(x) from facebook.js
</script>
```

This is a basic example to get you started.  If you have any more specific questions, I would be happy to assist where I can.